# jQuery content changed not initializing the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, admin

I'm creating an Admin website that has a sidebar. If sidebar is clicked, it will change the main content using ajax request and if success this will execute $('#page-wrapper').html(content); For example the content has an id of "#content".
I cant run functions on the changed content like $(#content).dataTable();. Please help.

```
// Function to CALL Ajax
rj.ajaxCall = function(options){
    // toSend url callbacks() callerror()
    console.log('ajaxCall');
    $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST',
        data        : options.toSend,
        url         : options.url,
        encode      : true,
        replace     : true,
        success     : function(data){options.callbacks(data);},
        error       : function(e){options.callerror(e);}
    });
};

// function to change main content on click of side bar 
rj.sidebar = function(){
    console.log('sidebar');
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#side-menu li a').on('click',function(event){
            console.log('side bar clicked');
            event.preventDefault();
            var loc = $(this).attr('location');
            console.log(loc);
            if(loc !== undefined && loc !== '#'){
                var request = {
                    toSend: {isCont:1},
                    url:loc,
                    callbacks: function(d){rj.contChange(d,loc);},
                    callerror: function(er){alert('Network Error. Please try again'); }
                };
                rj.ajaxCall(request); 
            }
        });
    });
};

//function to change the main content 
rj.contChange = function(cont,location){
    $('#page-wrapper').html(cont);
    history.pushState({},{},location);
};

// function to load DATA TABLE Js if content has id #dataTables-example
rj.initDataTable = function(){
    console.log('LOAD DATA TABLE');
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({responsive: true});
};

// execute javascripts
$(window).ready(function(){
    rj.initDataTable();
});

if ( $('#wrapper').length > 0 ){

    rj.initDataTable();

    rj.sidebar();
}
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Surely you appreciate we can't help if you don't post your code.

Comment: sorry, I updated my question. Im new at programming so please bear with me :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `rj.initDataTable` after the ajax success. try:

```
rj.contChange = function(cont,location){
    $('#page-wrapper').html(cont);
    history.pushState({},{},location);
    rj.initDataTable();
};
```